# Low graphics mode when installing 12.04 from a live CD

Tags: 12.04, hardware, mac, input, ppc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I have a PPC G4 tower with XCLAIM VR RAGE 128 PRO PCI DVI MAC, Microsoft mouse and a Crywolf Coolmac silicone keyboard.

I was able to live boot from the CD. Turned the computer on and it live booted. I got an error message saying it was *running in low graphics mode because it could not recognize the graphics card or the other input devices*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit msPeachy. According to this guide at [http://www.jonh.net/lppcfom-serve/cache/1043.html]
at yaboot I typed 
    live video=aty128fb:10,cmode:24 
I got the same result "your screen, grapics card, and input device settings could not be deticted correctly. You will nee to configure them yourself."
I will continue to try

Comment: Alright I'm just gonna take it to my local hacker space. they'll help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered on the PowerPC Known Issues page.  See the first point https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues#A12.04_Precise_Pangolin

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: If we are being pedantic then there is no question in the question.  So it is impossible to answer the question.